# How should I interpret this statement? $1<d,q<a$

Tags: inequality, notation

I have the following statement:

$$1< d,q < a .$$

Does this mean:

> $1 < d$ and $q < a$?

or does it mean:

> $1< d < a$ and $1< q<a$?

Comment: The second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

J.M. is correct, *assuming* that the author of the statement 
$$1 < d,q < a$$
formatted their statement the way they should have. One could imagine *intending* to say
$$\ldots 1<d,\text{ and }q<a\ldots $$
but forgetting the general rule to insert words between distinct expressions (to avoid precisely this kind of confusion). So, assuming they meant the single expression `$1 < d,q < a$`, then it does mean the second one, i.e. " $1<d<a$ and $1<q<a$ ". However, if they were sloppy and wrote two expressions right next to each other separated only by a comma, i.e. `$1<d$, $q<a$`, then they *intended* the first one, i.e. " $1<d$, and also $q<a$ ".

But it's best to assume people mean what they say unless there's reason to believe otherwise (e.g., the statement that $1<d$ and $q<a$ doesn't make sense in the context in which this appears). So you should read it as the second version.